# Make customer attribute unique

Tags: admin, attributes, customer, validation

is it possible to make a customer attribute unique, preferably on a website basis bit if not then globally?

I cant see how to do this.

Similar to the email address

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The customer attributes has no `is_unique` option which is available for product attributes. The uniqueness of email is verified programatically in `\Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer::_beforeSave`. So you can just mimic it for your attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this from magento backend.

1. Go to Magento Admin Panel.
2. Go to Customers -> Manage Attributes.
3. create new attribute or edit existing one.
4. Select Unique Value YES.

Comment: there is no Manage Attributes for customers. Maybe you have an extension or something. Or maybe you are on Enterprise version.

Comment: Yes , free extension is available for that.

Comment: @Pratik: You should share the name/link of the extension to help future Magento developers. Then I will upvote this answer :)